# Validation to make sure time difference is inside 2 hours

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, validation

I have start time and end time in my asp.net web application. Now i want to validate that if start time is selected say 10:00 AM then end time should be selected with the gap of 2 hours or less. Hence if i select 01:00 PM as a end time, then this should not happen.

How can i validate the same?

Comment: Have you investigated custom validators?

Comment: Yes, but i am not sure how that works when validating the timings come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use addition or subtraction on a DateTime class it returns a TimeSpan which can be compared in a conditional.

When creating a new TimeSpan class you can set the hours minuets and seconds in this form:

```
new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);
```

In your case you want to use:

```
new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);
```

Try something like this:

```
//Assuming you created your variables and assigned them somewhere above
DateTime startTime, endTime;
if(endTime - startTime > new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0)) {
    //validation error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a CompareValidator with type=DateTime to make sure EndTime > BeginTime. This will also validate they're both  valid Time  values.
2. Use a CustomValidator (C# and optionally JavaScript) to enforce the 2 hour rule.
3. Optionally add 1 or 2 RequiredFieldValidators

Comment: How to use customvalidator to enforce the 2 hour rule?

Comment: Just doubleclick and write out the C# event: decode the strings form 2 textboxes, subtract, check diff.TotalMinutes < 120.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can use a custom validation implementation. This would check that the current time selected 'start' was no more than 2 hours previous (or exactly dependent on your conditions).

Another thing to look at is 'range-validation' which should accommodate your requirements. Take a look here on MSDN for examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx#aspnet-validateaspnetservercontrols_topic5